# Invalid SSL certificate only on my Linux machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chrome, ssl, webserver

I'm hosting a website and my DNS server is from NameCheap, I bought an SSL certificate over there and configure it through nginx, everything were fine, but one day chrome started to complain that the certificate is now invalid (and the expiry date is not yet passed), my website is lodugo.com, this also happens with some other specific pages which I don't remember right now, but it only happens to my personal linux laptop, any other device in any other network, local or over the internet, does not have the problem

The most interesting thing is, if I use chrome in incognito mode over my personal linux laptop, it won't complain about the certificate.

I'm posting this here as it looks like the OS is rejecting the certificate itself, or that's what chrome says:

```
This server could not prove that it is lodugo.com; its security certificate is not trusted by your computer's operating system. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

I already checked the basics, my time and date are fine, other devices works fine in any case scenario, I haven't touch anything on the server side. Anyone can help with a hint or explanation of what can be happening?

Here you can find pictures of the  certificate with the error and in incognito mode (without the error and on the same machine)

Error: 
[image: Error]

Incognito with no error:
[image: Incognito]

Details tab with error:
[image: Details tab with error]

Details tab in incognito
[image: Details tab in incognito]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information. Explain "it only happens to me, if I try to access from any other device to my site chrome won't complain at all". What is the difference between "your device" and "any other device". Are they in the same local network or do they use different internet connections? Are you in a company network which might intercept connections? Please add details about the key and certificate as shown by the browsers on "your device" and on "any other device" (if different)

Comment: Edited, please check it out, I don't know what else to add to make it clear

Comment: I can see that only in incognito mode it shows "SSL Server Certificate". Is there any difference on the Details tab?

Comment: I added pictures for the details tab, the only different is the certificate hierarchy, I checked all the other details and they all match each other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like Chrome doesn't have access to the necessary CA certificate.  A quick check with [ssllabs.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) suggests that your site is missing an intermediary certificate.  When you purchase a certificate they will usually provide you with an intermediate certificate as well as your own.

Often browsers will only store root CA certificates and expect the web-server to send the intermediate along with the web-server's own certificate.  The intermediate certificate is signed by a root CA the browser already knows, the web-server's certificate is signed by the intermediate.  This creates a chain of trust.  But that chain is broken when the browser doesn't have access to the intermediate certificate.

To install this on nginx, you just roll the two together, putting your certificate first in the file:

```
cat my_certificate.crt intermediate.crt > certificate_for_nginx.crt
```

---

I'm not sure how chrome manages its certificates, I was under the impression it managed it's own.  However if it really is using the operating system's own certificates then you can test if your website is well configured for your Linux using:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
```

When I try this for your site I get:

```
...
Start Time: 1583258842
Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
Extended master secret: yes
```

Again, this shows the certificate can't be authenticated.  Usually that means it can't find the certificate, other errors tend to be more descriptive.

Comment: Going to check this ASAP

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I was using an SSL certificate from NameCheap, and NameCheap delivers the certificate (.crt) and the intermediate certificates (.ca-bundle), you answer pointed what I need to do, and I followed this https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9419/33/installing-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx/ to combine both certificates in a single one. Using that on Nginx chrome set my website as secure again!